# java.lang.NumberFormatException in db2jcc.jar

Tags: java, spring, jar, db2, numberformatexception

I am hitting this exception in a Java application. I extract the JAR file and try to check what is the root cause of this, but I fail to get it, because I can't debug on it.

I have the source JAR file, but every time I attach it in my workspace, it still shows me "the source attachment does not contain the source for the file ad.class".

The following is the error stack:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "A"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:59)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:460)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:510)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.ad.<init>(ad.java:80)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.f.<init>(f.java:55)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.b.ib(b.java:1760)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.p.a(p.java:2490)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.b.a(b.java:470)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.b.<init>(b.java:264)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:163)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1247)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1221)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2101)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1325)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:132)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 12 more
```

How can I debug this?

Comment: The message is clear. A is not a Number

Comment: If you Need more help, you have to add your code

Comment: @Jens, As you can see, all the class in the error stack is open source class file, not the code that I write. Thus, I am not sure why it throw this error.

Comment: no prior research about the exception

Comment: @Jens I found the solution and post the solution at below.

Comment: @Ravi I found the solution and post the solution at below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, its cause by the db2jcc.jar is too old for the db2 version. I found the solution here and manage to fix it.

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21625290

Comment: It was because you have not mentioned the prior research and effort you have put in and the things you have tried, additionally after you have researched and found the solution upvoting it.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the problem lies where you passed DBCP connection pool values - min count, max count etc. You have passed "A" in place of an integer.

Please check your spring context file or properties file where you provided database connection parameters.

Answer (score 0):

"A" is not a number you're probably trying to insert a string value into a variable or array that only allows numbers, make sure you declare your variables and arrays correctly. If your put atention in the error you are tryingtry put a String value into integer. I hope you can solved your error with my help pass a good day